# call graph as part of authentication to add claims .net 4.5

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, owin

i think the correct place is in SecurityTokenValidated but account is always null. i dont know how to set up the graphclient here?

SecurityTokenValidated = async (x) =>
{
IConfidentialClientApplication clientApp2 = MsalAppBuilder.BuildConfidentialClientApplication();
AuthenticationResult result2 = null;
var account = await clientApp2.GetAccountAsync(ClaimsPrincipal.Current.GetMsalAccountId());

```
                    string[] scopes = { "User.Read" };


                    // try to get an already cached token
                    result2 = await clientApp2.AcquireTokenSilent(scopes, account).ExecuteAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

                    var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(
                         new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(async (request) =>
                         {
                             //var token = await tokenAcquisition
                             //    .GetAccessTokenForUserAsync(GraphConstants.Scopes, user: context.Principal);
                             var token = result2.AccessToken;
                             request.Headers.Authorization =
                                 new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
                         })
                     );

                    var user = await graphClient.Me.Request()
                              .Select(u => new
                              {
                                  u.DisplayName,
                                  u.Mail,
                                  u.UserPrincipalName
                              })
                              .GetAsync();

                    var identity = x.AuthenticationTicket.Identity;
                    identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "test"));
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this sample: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/active-directory-dotnet-admin-restricted-scopes-v2/active-directory-dotnet-admin-restricted-scopes-v2/

You could follow this sample to get access token with `GetGraphAccessToken()` and make sure the signed-in user is a user account in your Azure AD tenant. Last thing is using Chrome in incognito mode this helps ensure that the session cookie does not get in the way by automatically logging you in and bypassing authentication.

> This sample will not work with a Microsoft account (formerly Windows
> Live account). Therefore, if you signed in to the Azure portal with a
> Microsoft account and have never created a user account in your
> directory before, you need to do that now. You need to have at least
> one account which is a directory administrator to test the features
> which require an administrator to consent.

```
var graphserviceClient = new GraphServiceClient(
    new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(
        (requestMessage) =>
        {
            // Get a token for the Microsoft Graph
            var access_token = await GetGraphAccessToken();
            requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", access_token);
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }));
}

private async Task<string> GetGraphAccessToken()
{
     IConfidentialClientApplication cc = MsalAppBuilder.BuildConfidentialClientApplication();
     var userAccount = await cc.GetAccountAsync(ClaimsPrincipal.Current.GetMsalAccountId());

     AuthenticationResult result = await cc.AcquireTokenSilent(new string[] { "user.read" }, userAccount).ExecuteAsync();
     return result.AccessToken;
}
```

Comment: i still get the same message unfortunately. No account or login hint was passed to the AcquireTokenSilent call. useraccount is null in graphaccesstoken

Comment: This is the root cause for me. This returns null: ClaimsPrincipal.Current.GetMsalAccountId() is there anyone know how it can be resolve?